# Python threads handling - join() - Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading

i m writing a script in which threads that do simple tasks start every 3 minutes . I m using the ***threading*** and ***schedule*** modules .

Because of the nature of multi-threading threads are using the same resources .

> What i need to achieve ?

When creating a new thread i would like to check if there is any runningthread; and if there is , then wait until the running thread terminates , then start the new thread .

> What i have tried ?

```
 import threading

def run_threaded(job_fn):
    job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_fn)
    bot.logger.info(" --------------No of active threads : "+threading.activeCount())
    job_thread.start()
    job_thread.join()
    bot.logger.info(" --------------No of active threads : " + threading.activeCount())


schedule.every(3).minutes.do(run_threaded, job)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

> Note: On the example above every job_thread needs 5 minutes to complete . Thus it creates 1 thread every 6 minutes .

From what i understand , the **job_thread.join()** line is joining the main thread ( with any other active threads) . Although the schedule , is blocked  thus no any other thread can be instantiated before the previous thread is finished . Is that correct ? And if yes , is this a good practice of doing this .?

And for the record .. Can the script execute other blocks of code while running a thread ? Or can it instantiate other threads, before the previous thread is finished , if they are going to execute an other job let's say ***job2*** ?

Comment: Yes. You can instantiate other threads before the previous thread is finished. In fact, that's really the whole point: If all that your main thread does in each `schedule` run is: (1) start work thread, (2) wait for work thread to end, then there is no point in creating a work thread at all. You can just do the same work in your main thread. The advantage of multithreading is that different threads can be executing *at the same time*. If you don't want/need to do multiple things at the same time, you don't need to use multithreading.

Comment: Ok thanks. Out of curiosity can u give me an example code that instantiate two threads simultaneously? And how can i check which of them is finished and which are still running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example showing several threads being started, each of which will terminate itself at a different time and how the main thread can determine when each has terminated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import threading
import time
import queue

class Worker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, duration, tqueue):
        self.duration = duration
        self.tqueue = tqueue
        super().__init__()
    def run(self):
        # Do real work here instead of just sleeping
        time.sleep(self.duration)
        # Tell parent we are gone by putting our instance to the queue
        self.tqueue.put(self)

def main():
    thr_duration = [2.0, 1.5, 0.5, 2.7, 1.25]
    workers = []
    thr_queue = queue.Queue()

    # Start all threads
    for dur in thr_duration:
        worker = Worker(dur, thr_queue)
        worker.start()
        workers.append(worker)
        print("Started thread {}, duration {}".format(worker.name, dur))

    # Wait for all threads to terminate
    while workers:
        worker = thr_queue.get()
        worker.join()
        print("Reaped thread {}".format(worker.name))
        workers.remove(worker)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```